# Get Custom Options dropdown size in magento?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

the following code is displaying all dropdown values but it should execute when i have the dropdown value is one

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($this->getProduct()->getId());  //product id
$i = 1;
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
    $values = $o->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $v) {
        print_r($v->getTitle());
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Note : So for that i want to get dropdown size for custom options in product page.

And I am using Magento CE1.7.0.2

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I tried this ' count($_options) ' but no use..Always its displaying 1 .

Comment: Can you post here sample values of `$o`, `$values` and `$v`, what is your current code returning and what is the expected output?

Comment: @Petr R I got that one check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
        $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($this->getProduct()->getId()); //product id
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $_option) {
            $values = $_option->getValues();
            foreach ($values as $v) {
                $j++;
                echo $v->getTitle(); // Displaying Dropdown values
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
        echo $j;
    ?>
```

Here $j is displaying the size of dropdown(custom options).

I hope it will helpful for some one

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[23/08/13 10:50:21 AM]  $i value will be size of drop down
[23/08/13 10:50:49 AM]  and we can also use count function of magento when get all options
[23/08/13 10:51:13 AM]  that will give exact number how much values in DD

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value with attribute like

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>

 <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>

 <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">-->
                   <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>                                                   
                    </select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId());
echo $optionsArr = count($product->getOptions());
```